# unique form field validation in extjs4

Tags: forms, field, unique, extjs4

Is there a cleaner way to define unique form field in extjs. Below is a sample code that is checking on client UID on client creation/edition. This code is working but has some bugs - for example on client creation if you enter a value that is already present in DB validator returns true until you unfocus the field.

```
Ext.define('AM.view.client.UniqueField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    alias : 'widget.uniquefield',

    vtype: 'UniqueUid',

    initComponent: function() {

    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {

        UniqueUidMask : /[0-9]/i,
        UniqueUid : function(val,field) {
            if (val.length < 9) {
                Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
                    UniqueUidText: 'Company ID is too small'
                });
                return false;
            } else {
              var paste=/^[0-9_]+$/;
              if (!paste.test(val)) {
                Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
                    UniqueUidText: 'Ivalid characters'
                });
                return false;
               } else {

                 var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(field.up('form'),{msg:'Please wait checking....'});  
                     mask.show();
                 var test= 0;
                 var store = Ext.create('AM.store.Clients');
                     store.load({params:{'uid':val, 'id': Ext.getCmp('client_id').getValue()}});
                     store.on('load', function(test) {
                      mask.hide();
                        if(parseInt(store.getTotalCount())==0){
                         this.uniqueStore(true);
                        }else{
                           Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
                              UniqueUidText: 'Company ID is already present'
                           });
                         this.uniqueStore(false);
                        }
                     },this)

                return true;    
               }
            }}
      },this);       


    this.callParent(arguments);

    },

    uniqueStore: function(is_error){

        Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        UniqueUidMask : /[0-9]/i,
        UniqueUid : function(val,field) {
            if (val.length < 9) {
                Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
                    UniqueUidText: 'Company ID is too small'
                });
                return false;
            } else {
              var paste=/^[0-9_]+$/;
              if (!paste.test(val)) {
                Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
                    UniqueUidText: 'Ivalid characters'
                });
                return false;
               } else {

                 var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(field.up('form'),{msg:'Please wait checking....'});  
                     mask.show();

                 var store = Ext.create('AM.store.Clients');
                     store.load({params:{'uid':val, 'id': Ext.getCmp('client_id').getValue()}});
                     store.on('load', function(test) {
                      mask.hide();
                        if(parseInt(store.getTotalCount())==0){
                         this.uniqueStore(true);
                        }else{
                         this.uniqueStore(false);
                        }
                     },this)

                return is_error;    
               }
            }}
      },this); 

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using server side validation?

I answered to similar issue here: [extjs4 rails 3 model validation for uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414269/extjs4-rails-3-model-validation-for-uniqueness/7705704)

Obviously you can change it to use "ajax" instead of "rest" proxy.