# extjs4 rails 3 model validation for uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, extjs, model

i m working with extjs 4 & rails 3.
 I want to have validation for **uniqueness** of field that is on extjs **form**.
 I want to have validation on **Rails model** for uniqueness, so i have done follwing on my rails model :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :search_key, :message => "Duplicate value found"
```

I am inserting new values of form into store as follows :

```
store.add(values);
```

If validation fails, the record does not get inserted into database.
Now I want to pop an alert box indicating that the entry is duplicate when validation fails, so that user can edit field. 
How can i make this communication betwn rails controller & extjs form for validation?
Also would rails callback will be useful in it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to pass messages returned from server to extjs app, I assume you can modify this to suit your need, or let me know if I need to clarify anything:

**Extjs**

---

in model, add:

```
proxy: {
  type: 'rest',
  url: '/manifest-items',
  reader: {
    type: 'json', // We expect the server to give us a JSON string as a response
    root: 'rows',
    totalProperty: 'total',
    messageProperty: 'message',
  }
},
```

**Rails Controller**

---

Then, in both cases of error or success, returned response should be:

```
render :json => {:success => false, :message => "some error", :rows => [something], :total => x}.to_json
```

**Back to Extjs**

---

In extjs, the message can be accessed as follows:

**important**: note the difference between getting error message in failure and success cases.

```
manifestItem.save({
  success: function(records, operation) {
    Ext.Msg.alert(operation.resultSet.message);
  },
  failure: function(records, operation) {
    Ext.Msg.alert(operation.error);
  }
});
```

Comment: thats exactly what im trying to do but ur exemple is not clear to me at all!